# How to select uncommon entry from 2 tables

Tags: sql

```
TableA                     TableB

Id Name                    Id Role
1  abc                     1  Test
2  xyz 
3  zxc
```

I want output as all Ids from table A which are not present in table B

O/p

```
Id Name
2  xyz
3  zxc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableA
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (Id,Name ) NOT IN (SELECT Id,Name FROM TABLE_2)
```

**Edit** (after question was formatted properly):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TABLE_2)
```